# rt.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java

I am trying to find url for MANIFEST.MF of java runtime (rt.jar).

This method does NOT work:

searching through enumeration returned by

```
classLoader.getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

This method DOES work:

get URL by

```
url = classLoader.getResource("java/io/File.class");
```

and then

```
url = new URL( url, "../"); // to io
url = new URL( url, "../"); // to java
url = new URL( url, "../"); // to root
url = new URL( url, "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

and it is correct since I can read Manifest from it.

I am a bit confused why using simple getResources does not work ?

My platform: Mac OS X 10.8.2 (up to date), oracle java (up to date):

java version "1.7.0_15"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_15-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: have you tried File.class.getClassLoader.getResource("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF") ?

Comment: Not yet on Mac, but on Linux (same java):  

 static void test3() {
  System.out.println("Test3: from File.class classLoader");
  ClassLoader c = File.class.getClassLoader();
  if (c == null) {
   System.out.println("Null classloader for File.class");
  } else {
   show(c.getResource(META_INF_MANIFEST_MF));
  }
 }
  
gives me:  
    Test3: from File.class classLoader
    Null classloader for File.class